# Custom library could not be found in ASP.NET5 MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use a custom library in an ASP.NET5 MVC6 application. I have the reference already. Here is my BaseController class, it gives no error in design time-

```
using EnDecryptor;
using LogExpress.ExceptionLogger;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected void LogException(Exception exception)
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString(); 
        ExceptionLog.Create(exception, path);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error while compiling -

> The type or namespace name 'LogExpress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my project.json-

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "CustomExceptions": "1.0.0-*",
        "EnDecryptor": "1.0.0-*",
        "LogExpress": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-beta-23409"
        }
    }
},
```

Any help?

Comment: What happens in your ASP.net application if you click on Add Reference and point it to your other project that is open in the solution.

Comment: I can't find the LogExpress package on NuGet. If it's a project, ensure that it supports `dnxcore50`. If you don't need to be cross-plat, just remove the whole `dnxcore50` from your `project.json`.

Answer (score 2):

The external class library you want to use is probably developed with a full *.NET Framework*, thus can't be used in a project targeting *.NET Core CLR*.

Try remove the whole `dnxcore50` entry in your `project.json` file.

You will loose the ability to run your project cross-platform but there is no other way of doing this unless the provider of the class library decides to port it to *Core CLR*.